# Publish ClientApp\dist under different name

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, csproj, msbuild-task

I have a .NET Core application (Razor Pages) and another VueJS app inside under ClientApp folder. Publishing the compiled SPA is done using the "famous" snippet that you can find all over the Internet:

```
  <Target Name="PublishClientApp" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)\dist\**" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

However, the SPA is published under ClientApp/dist folder (mirroring the solution structure). I would like to publish it under app/ folder, but I am not sure how to change this msbuild task. My guess is that there is something in this fragment - @(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)'), but trying to adjust it didn't give me any result.

```
Solution Structure    Published Folder      Desired Structure
\                     \                     \
 - ClientApp           - ClientApp           - app ( <- dist folder content here )
   - dist                - dist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the metadata of the generated `ResolvedFileToPublish` items to a different structure:

```
<RelativePath>app\%(DistFiles.RecursiveDir)%(DistFiles.Filename)%(DistFiles.Extension)</RelativePath>
```

Note that `%(DistFiles.RecursiveDir)` resolves to the directory components matched against the `**` wildcard in the `<DistFiles>` definition.